# Google talk gadget code from your website

Tags: gwt, google-talk, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

i would like to have a google talk button on my website to launch google chat option

i know it used to be possible but i can't find the code for it.
the Hangout video button code is available at the below address.
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button

But i can't find one for the chat option that is available via google plus profiles and gmail...

i would really like to launch the google talk option via a button directly from my website for a text chatting option... can anyone help please :) ???

Answer (score 0):

There used to be such a button till May, 2013

[google talk button](http://dancameron.org/general/google-talk-button/)

But now, it has been replaced by hangouts

[Google talk official documentation](https://developers.google.com/talk/)

"We announced a new communications product, Hangouts, in May 2013. Hangouts will replace Google Talk and does not support XMPP."